# R data frame merge by multiple columns in df.x

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Is it possible to merge by multiple column in df_a

For example if I have df_a and df_b, where my df_a is looking like

```
SKS1 SKS2
UXCC77  NA
UXCC00  NA
UXCC00  UXCD00
UXCD00  NA
UXCD60  NA
UXME10  NA
```

and df_b is have the descriptions for my SKS codes.

```
SKS desc
UXCC77  Left Leg
UXCC00  Right Leg
UXCD00  Right Arm
UXCD60  Left Arm
UXME10  Head
```

and etc.

I wish to do something like

`new_df <- merge(x = df_a, y = df_b, by.x = paste0("SKS", 1:ncol(df_a)), by.y = "SKS", all.x = TRUE)`

So that my output is

```
SKS1 SKS2 Desc1 Desc2
UXCC77  NA Left Leg NA
UXCC00  NA Right Leg NA
UXCC00  UXCD00 Right Leg   Right Arm
UXCD00  NA Right Arm NA
UXCD60  NA Left Arm NA
UXME10  NA Head NA
```

or with only one desc where a "/" is seperating the descriptions.

So that my output is

```
SKS1 SKS2 Desc1
UXCC77  NA "Left Leg"
UXCC00  NA "Right Leg"
UXCC00  UXCD00 "Right Leg"/"Right Arm"
UXCD00  NA "Right Arm"
UXCD60  NA "Left Arm"
UXME10  NA "Head"
```

dput of df_a

```
structure(list(SKS_koder_samlet = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
5L, 6L), .Label = c("UXCC00", "UXCC00/UXCD00", "UXCC77", "UXCD00", 
"UXCD60", "UXME10"), class = "factor"), SKS1 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("UXCC00", "UXCC77", "UXCD00", 
"UXCD60", "UXME10"), class = "factor"), SKS2 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("UXCC00", "UXCC77", "UXCD00", 
"UXCD60", "UXME10"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Where does "Desc2" come from?

Comment: Since I in df_a row 3 have two SKS codes, then by merging it add the correspoding descriptions.

Comment: @Cettt Sometimes a scan can have up to 8 SKS codes, so I would have from SKS1 to SKS8 and that does not seem viable. 
This is just for PET scan, I also have CT and so on.

Comment: @KaZyKa I see. How about a loop? Iterating over the columns of `df_a`?

Comment: @Cettt yeah I managed to solve it with a loop. It is a bit ugly but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

one possibility would be to use `merge` twice, like this:

```
merge(x = merge(x = df_a, y = df_b, by.x = "SKS1", by.y = "SKS", all.x = TRUE),
      y = df_b, by.x = "SKS2", by.y = "SKS", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("1", "2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

So `desc2` is just the value of `desc` but when `SKS2` is not NA:

```
library(dplpr)
new_df <- merge(x=df_a, y=df_b, by.x = 'SKS1',by.y='SKS', all.x=TRUE) %>% 
                rename(desc1 = desc)
new_df$desc2 <- new_df$desc
new_df$desc2[is.na(new_df$SKS2)] <- NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like

```
library(dplyr)

df <- left_join(df_a, df_b, by = c("SKS1" = "SKS", "SKS2" = "SKS"))

df$desc.y <- replace_na(df$desc.y, "")

df %>%
mutate(body_parts = ifelse(length(desc.y) > 1, paste0(desc.x,"/",desc.y),paste0(desc.x))
```

I'm running around this morning so I have no idea if this would even work, but just an idea to start out with. There might be an issue with the regex in the mutate but I'm not sure.